# Converting MongoDB query using aggregate to PHP driver aggregate query

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, laravel-5

I have the following query working in mongoDB but its not working in PHP.
MongoDB Query

```
db.energy_meter.aggregate(
{
  $unwind: {
        path:"$KeyValues", 
        includeArrayIndex:"arrayIndex", 
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true 
    }
},
{
  $project: {
        timestamp:{ 
          "$add":["$EventTS",{"$multiply":[60000,"$arrayIndex"]}] 
        } ,
        "RPhaseVoltage":"$KeyValues.RPhaseVoltage",
        arrayIndex:1,
        }
}
);
```

Above query is converted to PHP

```
 $cursor = DB::collection('energy_meter')->raw(function($collection)
                {
                    return $collection->aggregate([                   
                        [ 
                            '$unwind' => 
                                ['path' => '$KeyValues'],
                                ['includeArrayIndex' => 'arrayIndex'],
                                ['preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => 'true']
                        ],

                        [ 
                            '$project' => 
                                [
                                    'timestamp' => [
                                        '$add' => [
                                                '$EventTS',
                                                ['$multiply' => [60000, '$arrayIndex']]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [
                                    'MainsInputVoltagev' => ['$KeyValues.MainsInputVoltagev']
                                ],
                                [
                                    'arrayIndex' => 1
                                ]
                        ]
                    ]);
                });
```

I am getting following error

```
RuntimeException in Aggregate.php line 168: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
```

What is problem in my converted php query? Please suggest resolution of above problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should always convert normal query to array decode. json_decode should make query for PHP driver and json_encode should give query mongodb query parameters.

```
(
{
  $unwind: {
        path:"$KeyValues", 
        includeArrayIndex:"arrayIndex", 
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true 
    }
},
{
  $project: {
        timestamp:{ 
          "$add":["$EventTS",{"$multiply":[60000,"$arrayIndex"]}] 
        } ,
        "RPhaseVoltage":"$KeyValues.RPhaseVoltage",
        arrayIndex:1,
        }
  }
 )
```

Like this :

```
array(
  array(
     '$unwind' => array(
        'path' => '$KeyValues', 
        'includeArrayIndex' =>"arrayIndex", 
        'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays'=> true 
     )
   ),
  array(
    '$project' => array(
        'timestamp' => array( 
          '$add'=>[ '$EventTS',array('$multiply'=>[60000,'$arrayIndex'])] 
        ) ,
        "RPhaseVoltage" => '$KeyValues.RPhaseVoltage',
        'arrayIndex' =>1,
      )
   )
)
```

If you have at least PHP5.4, you can use simpler array syntax. Replace `array(` with `[` and `)` with `]` for array.

```
[                   
   [ 
      '$unwind' => [
           'path' => '$KeyValues',
           'includeArrayIndex' => 'arrayIndex',
           'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => 'true'
      ]
   ],
   [ 
      '$project' => [
            'timestamp' => [
                '$add' => [
                        '$EventTS',
                        [ '$multiply' => [60000, '$arrayIndex'] ]
                ]
            ],
            'MainsInputVoltagev' => '$KeyValues.MainsInputVoltagev',
            'arrayIndex' => 1
      ]
   ]
]
```